# Why can I bind values to values at Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax, binding

If I will start `ghci` and enter something like `4 = 5` or `1.2 = 3.4` it will accept it but nothing is printed. However, after this 4 is still 4 and not 5. Why didn't GHC throw any error like "cannot assign to literal"?

Comment: I don't know, but I'm guessing it's because it's lazily evaluated and you never cause the bind to be performed, similar to `let (Just x) = Nothing in "foo"` and unlike `let ! 2 = 3 in "foo"` where BangPatterns are used to make the binding strict.

Comment: I don't have time to write up an answer, but yes, it's as @thatotherguy says. Nothing uses the binding, so the failed pattern match is never detected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider

```
> let 4=5 in 4
4

> let x@4=5 in x
*** Exception: <interactive>:1423:5-9: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern x@4
```

The returned `4` in the first snippet does not refer to the `4` in LHS. The returned `4` is just another literal.

The returned `x` in the second does, and so the pattern `4` (not a literal `4`) is matched with the value of the literal `5`. And that matching fails.

Anyway this does not of course affect any subsequent interactions because the binding is confined to the `let` expression. And if you use `let` without the `in` as in older versions of GHCi, to indeed affect the following interactions, there's nothing to force that binding at all, so it stays idle and void.